# Is there any REST API available to list owners of an azure resource group?

Tags: azure, role-based-access-control, azure-rbac

The REST API which is available to [list role assignments of a resource group by MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-rest) results with few properties in which neither DisplayName nor RoleDefinitionName specified. But all the expected details could be fetched using PowerShell as stated in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-powershell).

Need to fetch the same details via an api call. Is there any possible way or REST API currently available to fetch details of all the Owners of a particular resource group in Azure?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [MS graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to list the owners of resource groups：

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/owners
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried this using graph api earlier but was getting response with error as `"message": "Resource '{id}' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."`. The {id} used to query was subscription id of the resource group. Could you please let me know if it's the right way to query?

Comment: this is for O365 groups, not Azure Resource Groups.

Comment: @DerekGusoff, yes thanks. It's not for Azure RG's! Think there is no api available to get the details for resource group owners.